# Symfony 2.7 - Nested collections form types and choices

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am currently learning Symfony 2 framework and struggling a little bit on nested collections form types.

I am trying to build a simple nested collections form with the entities modeled as the following:

```
MySurvey has many MyQuestions
MyQuestions has many MyAnswer
Each MyAnswer holds a possible value for the linked MyQuestion
```

My objective is to have a form that displays all questions from the survey and for each question that display all available answer as radio buttons (choices).
I am able to display answers as text fields but not as choices...

Here is my code:

Here are the entities:

```
class MySurvey
{
    ....

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyQuestion")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="my_survey_questions",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="survey_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
     protected $questions;

...
}

class MyQuestion
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyAnswer")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="question_answers",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="answer_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
     protected $answers;

...
}

class MyAnswer
{
    ....

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $value;

...
}
```

Here are my form types:

```
class MySurveyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('questions', 'collection', array('type' => new MyQuestionFormType()));
    }

    ...
}


class MyQuestionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('answers', 'collection', array('type' => new MyAnswerFormType()));
    }

    ...
}

class MyAnswerFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('value');
    }

    ...
}
```

And here is my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<form  method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {% set i = 0 %}
    <ol>
        {% for question in form.questions %}
            <br />
            <li>
                {{ questions[i].title }}<br /><br />
                {% set j = 0 %}
                {% for answer in question.answers %}
                    {{ form_widget(question.answers[j]) }}
                    {% set j = j + 1 %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% set i = i + 1 %}
            </li>
       {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried to change my buildForm function in MyQuestionFormType in order to select the proper answers to the question. But in order to get this solution working I need to have access to the answers of each questions, and I don't know how to get this done.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder->add('answers', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:MyAnswer',
        'choices' => ???
     ));
}
```

If I pass my survey as a parameter in the controller, is there a way to get a "the current question" value in my MyQuestionFormType so that I can retrieve its answers ?

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MySurveyFormType($survey->getQuestions()), $survey);
```

Any help appreciated !

Thanks a lot